# if else comparing array to string

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have the following `if-else`:

```
if (entity.length > depot.length) {
    for (var i = 0 ; i < entity.length; i++) {
        promises.push(this.getDataFromREST(security, i));
        console.log(entity, depot)
    }
} else {
    for (var i = 0 ; i < depot.length; i++) {
        promises.push(this.getDataFromREST(security, i));
        console.log(entity, depot)
    }
}
```

Where `entity` and `depot` are arrays, but if they are not holding data they `= "NULL"`.

Basically,for the purposes of this explanation, I want the length of `"NULL"` to be read as 0, or `if` `entity` is an array of length 1+ and `depot` is a string - the condition `entity.length > depot.length` is met.

Comment: so `depot` could be an array *or* a string? Did I understand that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If both `entity` and `depot` can be either "NULL" string or a valid array, you can simply make a check for `"NULL"`, calculate its length once and use one loop:

```
var loopLength = Math.max(entity === 'NULL' ? 0 : entity.length, 
                           depot === 'NULL' ? 0 : depot.length);

for (var i = 0 ; i < loopLength; i++) {
    promises.push(this.getDataFromREST(security, i));
    console.log(entity, depot)
}
```

This loop will run only if at least `entity` or `depot` is not `"NULL"` string and a valid non-empty array.

Comment: Ah, excellent.  I will try this then I have the time and get back.

Comment: This is a cool way of getting the loop length but this will not work in the case that one of them is a string try it out `entity="NULL"` , `depot = [1]`. The `loopLength` should be equal to `1` not `4`

Comment: @OmarMowafi Oh, now I see, it is a string "NULL". I thought it is a `null` value. See my update.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev yep that works correctly. My solution also works. I don't understand why I got a down vote :(

Comment: @OmarMowafi Probably, because of code duplication. I will give you an upvote if you get rid of it :)

Comment: Couldn't wait, works like an absolute charm, thanks for this.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I updated the code kept it with an if condition and removed the duplicate code.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is define a function length as follow

```
function length(s){
   if(s === "NULL") return 0;
   else return s.length;
}
```

Then write your code as you did but using this function for length

```
    var entityLength = length(entity);
    var depotLength = length(depot);

    if (entityLength > depotLength) 
       var loopLength = entityLength;
    else
       var loopLength = entityLength;


    for (var i = 0 ; i < loopLength; i++) {
        promises.push(this.getDataFromREST(security, i));
        console.log(entity, depot)
    }
```